# UpdateResource, no error, but resource not added. Why?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I want to write a simple configurator program based on resources. I use Windows API function to update resources of stub.exe. Application shows no error, but resource isn't added (some times exe file gets corrupted!). When I open stub.exe in ResourceHacker there are no resources.

My code is:

```
#include <Windows.h>

#define LANGUAGEID 1033

HANDLE hUpdate;
char szStubPath[MAX_PATH];
char DeadCode[] = "0xDEADC0DE";
unsigned int error = 0;

int main()
{

    GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, szStubPath);
    lstrcat(szStubPath, "\\stub.exe");

    hUpdate = BeginUpdateResource(szStubPath, FALSE);
    if(hUpdate == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(0, "BeginUpdateResource failed.", 0, MB_OK+MB_ICONERROR);
        error = 1;
    }
    if(UpdateResource(hUpdate, RT_STRING, TEXT("CURRENT"), LANGUAGEID, &DeadCode, 11) == FALSE)
    {
        MessageBox(0, "UpdateResource failed.", 0, MB_OK+MB_ICONERROR);
        error = 1;
    }
    if(EndUpdateResource(hUpdate, FALSE) == FALSE)
    {
        MessageBox(0, "EndUpdateResource failed.", 0, MB_OK+MB_ICONERROR);
        error = 1;
    }

    if(error == 0)
    {
        MessageBox(0, "stub.exe - Resource added.", "Info", 0);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox(0, "stub.exe - Adding resource failed.", "Info", 0);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

There are no errors, but resource isn't added (some times exe file gets corrupted!), why? What is wrong?

Edit:
**I want to add information that stub.exe is written in MASM32 and config.exe is written in Visual C++. Is there a chance that different programming languages makes problems?**

Regards, David

Comment: UpdateResource is quite troublesome.  Be sure to carefully read the MSDN article for it to know its restrictions.  Especially pay attention to the first paragraph in the Remarks section.

Comment: I have written stub.exe to Visual C++. Now config.exe and stub.exe are in Visual C++ and are both working!